# acivemq, secure websockets, CA, security and same origin restrictions - How do I install a CA certificate?

Tags: ssl, activemq-classic, keystore, mqtt

Has anyone managed to install a CA certificate into an activemq instance? I've been doing google searches and reading the activemq documentation but I haven't found anything on how to use a pre-existing CA certificate in activemq.

I assume I install it into the activemq keystore. Is that correct? I'll be using it with websockets and mqtt on the client end.

Also, just in case my assumptions are incorrect, here's why I think I need to use my current CA certificate.
1) I have a web application and our users require communication with the server to be secure. All http traffic is secure.
2) All modern web browsers have a same-origin policy for websockets. They also seem to have a no-mixed-content policy. And so because my http traffic is secure I also have to use secure websockets. (I also have to run the activemq server at the same url)

I'd rather not tunnel the websocket traffic over http because then I have to worry about the apache configuration in addition to the activemq configuration - just another place for things to potentially go wrong.

Also, I don't transfer any sensitive information over the websocket so I could potentially leave it unsecured, but first, my users probably wouldn't understand that, but also it looks like browsers have a no-mixed-content policy.

Has anyone gone through what I'm going through? Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got this working, but ultimately I decided to tunnel my websockets communication through apache using the ws_tunnel module.

But to answer my question above, basically what you have to do is create a new java keystore based on your webserver keys, and then replace the apachemq java keystore with this new keystore. I was never able to successfully import the keys into the existing keystore.

For example, on my ubuntu server, my keys are:

```
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/star_astracorp_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/star_astracorp_com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/astracorp.com.intermediate.sha1.chcrt
```

I then export the key as pkcs12:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in /etc/apache2/ssl/star_astracorp_com.crt -inkey /etc/apache2/ssl/star_astracorp_com.key -out server.p12 -name emsu1 -CAfile ca.crt -caname root
```

I then import the pkcs12 into a new java keystore:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass password -destkeypass password -destkeystore server.keystore -srckeystore /etc/apache2/ssl/server.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass password -alias emsu1
```

Then, in my apachemq directory I move the old broker.ks out of the way and rename server.keystore as kroker.ks and restart activemq.

One of my servers had .pem files for its keys. The process was still similar, however I had to go into OS X's keystore utility to get the password of the key.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in /etc/certificates/ems-dev.local.EDA65671FF2C9CE7DAA56E9AD8E4E5F3F2675C79.cert.pem -inkey /etc/certificates/ems-dev.local.EDA65671FF2C9CE7DAA56E9AD8E4E5F3F2675C79.key.pem -out server.p12 -name emsdev -CAfile ca.crt -caname root
```

you will then be asked for the key - copy and paste it from the key util.

Then, the process to create a new keystore is the same:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass password -destkeypass password -destkeystore server.keystore -srckeystore /etc/certificates/server.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass password -alias emsdev
```